# How replace just leading number for a string where those characters appear also as unit

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I have the following vector

```
vector <- c(31, 41, 51, 61, 32, 42, 52, 62, 33, 43, 53, 63,
            34, 44, 54, 64, 35, 45, 55, 65, 36, 46, 56, 66)
```

I would like just to replace the leading number without convert that number when it is found as unit digit

```
str_replace_all(vector, c('3' = 'Air', '4' = 'Car',
                          '5' = 'Polluted', '6' = 'Gas'))
```

The desired out is just is to use each final/unit digit as a marker meaning that for example:

wherever there is a `3(unit/digit)`, the code should convert it as:

```
'Air_(unit/digit)'
```

more clearly as:

```
#  [1] "Air_1"      "Car_1"      "Polluted_1"
#  [4] "Gas_1"      "Air_2"      "Car_2"     
#  [7] "Polluted_2" "Gas_2"      "Air_3"     
# [10] "Car_3"      "Polluted_3" "Gas_3"     
# [13] "Air_4"      "Car_4"      "Polluted_4"
# [16] "Gas_4"      "Air_5"      "Car_5"     
# [19] "Polluted_5" "Gas_5"      "Air_6"     
# [22] "Car_6"      "Polluted_6" "Gas_6"
```

Would you suggest any quick way to do this? Thanks

Comment: There is no `3(unit/digit)` in your string. There is `34` do you want that to be `AirCar` or `Air4`?? You need to use example of what you provided. You are using `3(unit/digit)` yet that is not in your example

Comment: It simply means  3+any unit after (31, 32, 33 and 34, all of them is composed by 3 + a unit or digit.

Comment: You should clarify that in your question, explicitly stating what you want. eg say `34` should be `Air_4` not `3(unit/digit)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we always have 2 digits, using arithmetic operators `%%` to get 1st digit and `%/%` to get remainder - the 2nd digit. Then paste all as desired:

```
paste(
  c('3' = 'Air', '4' = 'Car', '5' = 'Polluted', '6' = 'Gas')[
    as.character(vector %/% 10) ],
  vector %% 10, sep = "_")
#  [1] "Air_1"      "Car_1"      "Polluted_1"
#  [4] "Gas_1"      "Air_2"      "Car_2"     
#  [7] "Polluted_2" "Gas_2"      "Air_3"     
# [10] "Car_3"      "Polluted_3" "Gas_3"     
# [13] "Air_4"      "Car_4"      "Polluted_4"
# [16] "Gas_4"      "Air_5"      "Car_5"     
# [19] "Polluted_5" "Gas_5"      "Air_6"     
# [22] "Car_6"      "Polluted_6" "Gas_6"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution:

```
str_replace_all(vector, c('^3' ='Air_', '^4'='Car_',
                           '^5' = 'Polluted_', '^6' = 'Gas_'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for fancier solution, but is this what you're looking for?

```r
library("stringr")
vector <- c(31, 41, 51, 61, 32, 42, 52, 62, 33, 43, 53, 63, 34, 44, 54, 
            64, 35, 45, 55, 65, 36, 46, 56, 66)

paste0(
  str_replace_all(stringr::str_extract(vector, "[[:digit:]]"),
                  c('3' ='Air', '4'='Car',
                    '5' = 'Polluted', '6' = 'Gas')),
  "_(",
  str_extract(vector, "[[:digit:]]$"),
  ")"
)
#>  [1] "Air_(1)"      "Car_(1)"      "Polluted_(1)" "Gas_(1)"      "Air_(2)"     
#>  [6] "Car_(2)"      "Polluted_(2)" "Gas_(2)"      "Air_(3)"      "Car_(3)"     
#> [11] "Polluted_(3)" "Gas_(3)"      "Air_(4)"      "Car_(4)"      "Polluted_(4)"
#> [16] "Gas_(4)"      "Air_(5)"      "Car_(5)"      "Polluted_(5)" "Gas_(5)"     
#> [21] "Air_(6)"      "Car_(6)"      "Polluted_(6)" "Gas_(6)"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This assumes there are always two digits, and the first represents the category, and the second some sort of value.

Answer (score 1):

With `stringr`, you can supply a function into `str_replace()` to replace the match of the first number.

```r
library(stringr)

str_replace(vector, "^.",
  ~ c('3'= 'Air_', '4'= 'Car_', '5'= 'Polluted_', '6'= 'Gas_')[.x])

#  [1] "Air_1"      "Car_1"      "Polluted_1" "Gas_1"      "Air_2"      "Car_2"     
#  [7] "Polluted_2" "Gas_2"      "Air_3"      "Car_3"      "Polluted_3" "Gas_3"     
# [13] "Air_4"      "Car_4"      "Polluted_4" "Gas_4"      "Air_5"      "Car_5"     
# [19] "Polluted_5" "Gas_5"      "Air_6"      "Car_6"      "Polluted_6" "Gas_6"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `paste0` like this

```
> paste0(c("Air", "Car", "Polluted", "Gas")[vector %/% 10 - 2], "_", vector %% 10)
 [1] "Air_1"      "Car_1"      "Polluted_1" "Gas_1"      "Air_2"
 [6] "Car_2"      "Polluted_2" "Gas_2"      "Air_3"      "Car_3"
[11] "Polluted_3" "Gas_3"      "Air_4"      "Car_4"      "Polluted_4"
[16] "Gas_4"      "Air_5"      "Car_5"      "Polluted_5" "Gas_5"
[21] "Air_6"      "Car_6"      "Polluted_6" "Gas_6"
```